# Printing data from the csv file

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

I wanna ask how do I print the number of dentists respective in 2012 from the CSV file.

```py
import csv
csv_file = open('project.csv' , 'r')
data_file  = csv.reader(csv_file)
def opt_a():
   next(data_file)
   for row in data_file:
       i = row[1:]
       print(i)
opt_a()
```

This what I have tried but I will only be able to print out in rows.

Sample of data :

```
year,Private Dental Specialists,Private General Dental Practitioners,Public Dental Specialists,Public General Dental Practitioners
2008,116,864,47,268
2009,180,863,74,246
2010,185,874,87,267
2011,199,961,77,241
2012,203,1012,86,271
2013,219,1192,88,308
2014,216,1219,96,348
2015,215,1326,102,347
2016,219,1425,106,380
2017,232,1516,112,365
2018,189,1579,113,412
2019,237,1644,130,379
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please edit your question and inform what you expect the output to be ? Maybe also add a tag for the process/ language of your choice (seems to be Python ? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for loop, simply check if the first value of your row is 2012 :

```py
import csv
csv_file = open('project.csv' , 'r')
data_file  = csv.reader(csv_file)
def opt_a():
   next(data_file)
   for row in data_file:
       if row[0] == "2012":
           i = row[1:]
           print(i)
opt_a()
```